# iOS: How to check for software update from a third party app

Tags: ios, objective-c, settings

Objective C: I am working on an utility app and I want to check (from inside my app) if the iPhone's Software is up to date. Is that possible?

Comment: As far as I know there is no API for that. I bet Apple treat that as breaking privacy :)

Comment: Or maybe launch the Settings/General/Software Update from the app?

Comment: You cannot really do that either, sorry :) iOS is pretty well protected from this kind of actions :P

Comment: Ya It could be possible with MDM(Mobile device Management). But MDM is totally different concept with respect to apps. In this, you have to enroll your device with MDM server. It's an legal process with apple, mainly corporate will do this via admin

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to keep track of the latest version yourself [on a server somewhere](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=mWUMfR5z), retrieve it with a network call, then compare it with the current version using the string at `[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];`

```
 NSLog(@"%@", [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]); // 7.0.3
```